# Active resource after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I am using active resource version 3.2.1, I need a life cycle method like after_create where I can do some post initialization stuff.

I know this is coming in next version of active resource, was wondering how people solve this problem right now with older version.

Comment: I'm not having to deal with this problem, but you can always patch libraries and bend them as you see fit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
after_filter :some_method, :only => :create
```